# Calculator in Searchbox

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, result-source

I'm following the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloshm/archive/2012/12/16/how-to-use-query-rules-and-display-templates-to-detect-the-intent-of-your-users.aspx

to build a calculator out of the searchbox. I modified the regular expression to:

> \d+\s*[/+-/*]\s*\d+

But I don't get it working with e.g. 23462634746-4

[image]

The reason I think is, that there are no results found in my SharePoint Local Results.

I also tried the regex:

> [^d]*[/+/-/*/\][^d]*

But the calculator is only working if there is an item in SharePoint which contains something out of the query.

So I probably have to modifiy the query for the result block but only want the query to match if there is a calculation in the query.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query to something like "*" so you get a result.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but then the calculator appears every time. I only want to show the calculator if there is a calculation in the query.

Comment: It should only show if your rule is satisfied. Change the {SearchBoxQuery} part. I have this in my demo environment and it works fine.

Comment: No way, just changed the {SearchBoxQuery} to * and now it's working! Thanks Matthew!

Comment: Great! You are essentially telling the rule, go get any result. (Because you don't really care.) Thanks for the vote.

Answer (score 0):

I published now a Step-by-Step guide for the calculator in my [Blog](https://blog.afrait.com/calculator-in-searchbox/).

Don't be [afraIT.com](http://afraIT.com) to check it out.